# Filter nested data with array vales using lodash react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

Consider this example. I am using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15)

```
"data": {
    “places”: [
                {
            place: 1,
            place name: ‘123’
            location: [ 
                {
                    location_id: 1,
                    location_name: ‘xyz’
                },
                {
                    location_id: 2,
                    location_name: ‘abc’
                },
                {
                    location_id: 3,
                    location_name: ‘etc’
                },
            ]
        }, 
        {
            place: 2,
            place name: ‘456’
            location: [ 
                {
                    location_id: 1,
                    location_name: ‘xyz’
                },
                {
                    location_id: 3,
                    location_name: ‘abc’
                },
                {
                    location_id: 4,
                    location_name: ‘etc’
                },
            ]
        } ,
        {
            place: 3,
            place name: ‘123’
            location: [ 
                {
                    location_id: 5,
                    location_name: ‘xyz’
                },
                {
                    location_id: 6,
                    location_name: ‘abc’
                },
                {
                    location_id: 2,
                    location_name: ‘etc’
                },
            ]
        }   ]
}
```

I want to filter the above data with location_id if theres only one id to filter with then

```
var filterplaces = _.filter(data.places,{ location: [{ location_id: this.state.selectedLocationId}] });
```

it return proper filter data.
Know the issue is when there is more than one location_id then how should i pass array data to filter records.
lets say selectedLocationId will be array which has locationid [2,5].

Any help is appreciated 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it without lodash:

```js
data.places.forEach(element => 
     element.location.filter(obj => required_ids.indexOf(obj.location_id) > -1).length
     && filterplaces.push(element)
);
```

```js
var data = {
  "places": [{
      place: 1,
      place_name: "123",
      location: [{
          location_id: 1,
          location_name: "xyz"
        },
        {
          location_id: 2,
          location_name: "abc"
        },
        {
          location_id: 3,
          location_name: "etc"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      place: 2,
      place_name: "456",
      location: [{
          location_id: 1,
          location_name: "xyz"
        },
        {
          location_id: 3,
          location_name: "abc"
        },
        {
          location_id: 4,
          location_name: "etc"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      place: 3,
      place_name: "123",
      location: [{
          location_id: 5,
          location_name: "xyz"
        },
        {
          location_id: 6,
          location_name: "abc"
        },
        {
          location_id: 2,
          location_name: "etc"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
};

let required_ids = [1, 2];
var filterplaces = [];
data.places.forEach(element => element.location.filter(obj => required_ids.indexOf(obj.location_id) > -1).length && filterplaces.push(element));

console.log(filterplaces);
```

---

It could also be done using `some()`:

```js
filteredPlaces = data.places.filter(element => element.location.some((obj => required_ids.indexOf(obj.location_id) > -1)));
```

Comment: shrys its returing matched location i want complete places object  that contains required location ids.

Comment: `const filteredPlaces = data.places.filter(element => element.location.some(/* */));` would be more efficient and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [a function as your predicate instead of shorthand iteratee](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter):

```
var filterplaces = _.filter(data.places, function(place) {
  return this.state.selectedLocationIds.indexOf(place.location.location_id) >= 0;
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Iterates over elements of collection, returning an array of all elements predicate returns truthy for. The predicate is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).
Note: Unlike _.remove, this method returns a new array.

```
var filter = _.filter(data.places, function(p) {
  if (p.length === 1) {
// write logic to return true or not if locaion is onnly 1
} else {
// write logic for more than 1 location id 
}
});
```

https://lodash.com/docs/#filter
for more detaiols